# jQuery backgroundPosition not accepting multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate motion in my body's background image using variables as the coordinates, but it seems like jquery's backgroundPosition only accepts one value.  I tried a few things, like backgroundPosition: distance1 + " " + distance2, and backgroundPosition: distance1 + " -50px" (the value I want it to be at the whole time), but even if I set the top value in CSS, it just defaults to using my first value (left) for both.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
function shiftBoxes(distance1, distance2, id){
    activeBtn('pos' + id.substring(4));
    $("#boxMover").animate({
        marginLeft: distance1
    }, 500, function() {});
    $(document.body).animate({
        backgroundPosition: distance2
    }, 500, function() {});
}
//Add one of these for every box
//The distance to move to the next box is always -1804(*("#pos" + n) - 1) pixels
$("#pos1").click(function() {
    shiftBoxes('0', '-1400', '#box1');
});
$("#pos2").click(function() {
    shiftBoxes('-1804', '-1200', '#box2');
});
$("#pos3").click(function() {
    shiftBoxes('-3608', '-1000', '#box3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this example](http://www.boonex.ru/blogs/entry/JQuery-Background-Position-tutorial). It looks like you need parens around the values like so:

`.animate({backgroundPosition:"(-20px 94px)"}`

Answer (score 0):

The Property backgroundPostion accpets values as:

top left
bottom right
center left

or

x% Y% where the left top is 0% 0% and the right bottom is 100% 100%

or

xpos ypos where you can use any css units as %, pixels, em, etc.

and last

inherit

To use it you would have some like:

```
.style.backgroundPosition="center bottom";

or

.style.backgroundPosition = "20% 50%";
```

I hope this helps. Peace.